# get list of element with view child

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i create a genric form with form array in angular 8 .

i need to get all of tag if have `ViewChild` id .

but when i `console` the `ViewChild` it show me just one element not list of elemnt but i need show me list of element .

**whats the prblem ? how can i solve problem ???**

html :

```
   <ngx-mat-file-input #upload disabled="true" class="uploadFild" (change)="showPreview($event,i)" appearance="outline"
                            formControlName="file" type=file>
                        </ngx-mat-file-input>
```

ts :

```
    @ViewChild('upload', { static: false }) pRef: ElementRef[];

     function():void
     {
        this.pRef['disabled']=false;
        console.log(this.pRef)          
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `@ViewChildren` instead.

Example:

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, Directive, QueryList, ViewChildren} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({selector: 'child-directive'})
class ChildDirective {
}

@Component({selector: 'someCmp', templateUrl: 'someCmp.html'})
class SomeCmp implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChildren(ChildDirective) viewChildren !: QueryList<ChildDirective>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // viewChildren is set
  }
}
```

check the documentation: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren

Comment: i see this document but it not work beacuse i used the `ngx-mat-file-input`

Comment: Directive name in `@ViewChildren` help me to fix problem. Thanks!